# How to detect that multiple pdf.js rendering tasks have finished

Tags: promise, pdf.js

I am now trying to render a whole pdf file with multiple pages into my webpage and one canvas corresponds to one page. While I can put code in then() Promise for issues after single page's rendering, I found I cannot use $.when function to detect that all pages have been rendered. My current solution is rendering pages one by one and run my code in last page's then() Promise. I hope there is any other solutions!

Thanks!

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
var renderArray = new Array();
for (var pageNo = 0; pageNo < pdfPageArray.length; pageNo++)// All pages extracted by PDF.JS are stored in pdfPageArray
{
    var page = pdfPageArray[pageNo];
    var viewport = page.getViewport(printScale);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    $(canvas).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});
    var outputScale = getOutputScale(context);
    canvas.width = (Math.floor(viewport.width) * outputScale.sx) | 0;
    canvas.height = (Math.floor(viewport.height) * outputScale.sy) | 0;
    $(printPageDiv).append(canvas);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport
    };
    renderArray.push(page.render(renderContext));

}
return $.when.apply($, renderArray);//It seems this when function doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a tricky one.

jQuery promises do not assimilate promises from other libraries, they are not Promises/A+ complaint and they do not inter operate well with other promises. In fact `$.when` only works with jQuery promises.

Instead native promises, or the polyfill PDF.JS provides for those, or even a more capable promise library.

Change `$.when.apply($, renderArray)` to:

```
Promise.all(renderArray);
```

Some other tips - use `[]` instead of `new Array` (does the same thing) and you might want to consider doing a `.map` directly into the `Promise.all` to convey intent better.

Comment: You're welcome, this is a lot more jQuery's fault than anything else